# Issues in alarm in Android Application

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

i have a alarm application that should print a toast message every 1 minute.But it does that just once when Application is run for the first time.

here my code:

```
 private class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        MainActivity  m= new MainActivity ();
            private Timer mTimer;
            private TimerTask mTimerTask;

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
                    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG"); 
                    wl.acquire();                               Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm !!!!!!!!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Every 1 minute i print the tost message.                        wl.release();


            }
            public void SetAlarm(Context context) 
            { 
             AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
             Intent i = new Intent(context, ConnectivityReceiver.class); 
             PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);  
             am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute
             } 
             public void CancelAlarm(Context context)  { 
             Intent intent = new Intent(context, ConnectivityReceiver.class); 
             PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
             AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
             alarmManager.cancel(sender);  
             }
                    }
```

Comment: are you listening to me Leema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your this line

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 1, pi);
```

to

```
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + ( 1000 * 60 ), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi);
```

This will add one minute your `System.currentTimeMillis();` and will start after that time.

Comment: toast comes only one minute..not every 1 minute

Comment: I use same line & it is working here. you know something, we both develop same application.

Comment: oh really,,,k give any working code for every 10 minutes alarm

Comment: is it print for every 1 minutes

Comment: why you removed "accecpted" Leema ?

Answer (score 3):

Just do one thing,

in  the line `PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);`

replace with `PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, **someUniqueId**, intent, 0);`

where **uniqueId** is integer either u generate or declare as "i++" where i is `public static int i;`

Hope this will work